# Query To manage the commercial pression in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to manage the commercial pressure in SFMC and to set a query that feed a DATA extension.

This DE will be used as exluded data extension when sending the email.

So some question :

1-is there a query for subscribers who receive an email in the last 7 days for one BU and alsso a query for all Business unit?

2- I set this query but marketing cloud doesn't recognize this syntax (issue with the dd - DAY in the query):

```
  SELECT 
      s.SubscriberKey,
      s.EventDate AS Sent_Date,
      'False' AS Not_Opened
    FROM _Sent s
    LEFT JOIN _Open o
    ON s.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
      WHERE o.SubscriberKey IS NULL 
            AND
            CAST(s.EventDate AS DATE) >= CAST(DATEADD(dd, -60, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AS DATE) 
            AND
            CAST(s.EventDate AS DATE) < CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, there is not the capability to query each BU's _Sent data view from a single location.

What I would do is have each BU have a scheduled repeatable query that pulls the sent emails for the past 7 days and have them all put into a shared DE. I would then do a UNION query to pull all of these DEs into a single AllSentDE.

You then use this shared DE as your exclusion list across all BUs.

As to your second question, For `DateAdd()`, `dd` should be `day, dy, y` to mean Day ([ref](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp)).

Also `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` should be `GETDATE()` to gather the current server date/time.

Comment: Thanks @Gortonington for your answer. So if a make a query from the parent Bu it does'nt query all send view in the other Bu?                                                                               So, if i understand the send view and open and the others ones are specially restricted to the current Bu?

Comment: Correct. Only certain data views, like _Subscribers provide enterprise level info. Clicks, opens, sent etc. Are BU level only